# Getting The Title of a Youtube Video Using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube

I am trying to scrape the title of a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBBtxuHoV_g)  with the following python script. 
When I run my current code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBBtxuHoV_g")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"ytd-video-primary- 
info-renderer")))
print(element.text)
```

The output gives me

```
 Bryan Cranston, Kanye West, Will Smith SHOCKED by Magician David Blaine
 458,317 views
 3.5K
 76
 SHARE
```

How do I change my code so it just returns the title of the video? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like it would be simple enough to just take the first line of the output. `title = element.text.split('\n')[0]`

Comment: Yeah my question was a foolish one, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to get that title without using any hardcoded index then the following should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBBtxuHoV_g")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.title yt-formatted-string"))).text
print(element)
driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
Bryan Cranston, Kanye West, Will Smith SHOCKED by Magician David Blaine
```