# How to get Youtube Video Titles using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

How can I use selenium `webdriver` to get the YouTube video title, I tried to use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath[//a[@title="NAME OF VIDEO"]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting The Title of a Youtube Video Using Python/Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032139/getting-the-title-of-a-youtube-video-using-python-selenium)

Comment: @Simba Agreed on duplicate. However, not being a Lion King in this Jungle, I cannot vote to close...

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="NAME OF VIDEO"]')
```

You've forgotten the parenthesis and quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m00F8gAJJJo'
driver.get(url)
xpath = '/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info-renderer/div/h1/yt-formatted-string'

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
print(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract youtube video from the home page

```
videoTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]')
videoTitleText = videoTitle.text
```

else if you want to extract video title from the video page then you should use this

```
videoTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string')
videoTitleText = videoTitle.text
```